# Qual è il significato di "scalzare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> *Quegli industriali* erano, secondo mia madre, coloro che facevano dei loro – e dei nostri – passatempi la loro principale occupazione: “gli automobili,” lei diceva così, e "le films, buone solo per le cameriere e i lattai”, e l'opinione di mio padre era altrettanto limitata. [...] E che **scalzassero** la vecchia guardia, chiedendo di essere ammessi al Club o comprando le ville della collina... E con vero raccapriccio mia madre rifletteva sulla sorte della vecchia contessa di St-Pierre, costretta a vendere a un certo Fenoglio i pezzi più importanti della sua collezione d'arte... O dei Costamagna, che avevano ceduto il palazzo di famiglia a un industriale laniero, figlio di un maestro di scuola... che aveva dato un ballo esageratamente costoso... tartufi e ostriche *pour épater... épater* chi, poi?... Insomma, la prudenza suggeriva di tenersene saldamente alla larga, tanto poi quelli nemmeno ti invitavano.

Non capisco il senso del verbo "scalzare" in questo brano. Ho cercato il suo [significato nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scalzare/), ma nessuna delle accezioni riportate sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "che scalzassero la vecchia guardia" nel brano precedente?

Comment: Nel contesto significa:   Rimuovere o far rimuovere qualcuno  dal posto che occupa: *scalzare  qlcu. dalla carica di direttore.* http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scalzare.shtml - Nel contesto sembra che gli industriali volessero liberarsi del vecchi nobili (la vecchia guardia)  entrando nel loro Club o comperando le loro proprietà.

Comment: Proprio per quanto detto da @Josh61, credo che in questo caso la definizione più appropriata tra quelle proposte dal dizionario del Corriere della Sera sia «soppiantar[e qualcuno] in una carica, gener. con metodi sleali».

Comment: @Benedetta - non sono sicuro che "i metodi sleali"  siano il riferimento più corretto  in questo caso. A me sembra che il contesto sia quello di nobili indebitati o a corto di soldi che si sono trovati costretti a vendere a chi in quel momento poteva comperare. Il fatto che venissero "scalzati" dalle loro vecchie posizioni di potere è una conseguenza.

Comment: Anche il Treccani riporta “Meno com., fare in modo, con manovre più o meno subdole, che una persona venga allontanata dal posto o dalla carica che occupa, con l’intenzione di prenderne il posto”. A dire il vero, mi pare che “meno comune” sarebbe da togliere.

Comment: @Josh61 non sempre scalzare qualcuno da un posto vuol dire farlo con modi sleali. La definizione mi sembrava più adatta perché tiene insieme il fatto di togliere qualcuno da una posizione e prenderne il posto. In questo caso, i modi non sono sleali, ma certo si fondano sulla necessità dei nobili di trovare denaro.

Comment: @Josh61: Forse non si tratta propriamente di metodi sleali, ma il verbo descrive la mentalità dei genitori della narratrice, che non sono d'accordo con quello che sta succedendo ai nobili e quindi percepiscono i modi di fare degli industriali come "sleali" o "subdoli".

Comment: Grazie ai vostri commenti, adesso capisco più o meno il significato del verbo in questo contesto, ma qualcuno può scrivere la risposta?

Comment: Visto che @Josh61 ha dato la risposta nei commenti credo che sarebbe giusto che si lasciasse a lui di riportare il tutto come risposta vera e propria

Comment: @ErikvanDoren - you or any other user can post an answer, comments are not relevant with that respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riporto la risposta di Josh61 nei commenti:

> Nel contesto significa: Rimuovere o far rimuovere qualcuno dal posto che> occupa: scalzare qlcu. dalla carica di direttore. [dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scalzare.shtml](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scalzare.shtml)
>
> Nel contesto sembra che gli industriali volessero liberarsi del vecchi nobili (la vecchia guardia) entrando nel loro Club o comperando le loro proprietà.